# Gitlab build fails when I use <%- ejs tag

Tags: node.js, ejs

This is the log I'm getting on the pipeline, my team was using the <%= tag on an ejs file, and I had to make a change to use <%- and then the build does not works on gitlab ci, but when I try to build locally, it works. And I'm not using this "underscore" library mentioned in the error.

```
"build:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack"
```

- This is the script to run the build

  ERROR in ./views/forms/survey.ejs
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'underscore' in '/builds/ve/vsplatform/vsmanager/views/forms'
  @ ./views/forms/survey.ejs 1:0-21
  @ ./controllers/forms/surveyForm_controller.js
  @ ./initialization.js
  @ ./vsmanager.js
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 2
  npm ERR! VSHOW_HTML_PLATFORM@1.0.0 build:prod: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack`
  npm ERR! Exit status 2
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the VSHOW_HTML_PLATFORM@1.0.0 build:prod script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-25T16_22_43_830Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, the problem is that I haven't installed underscore on the project, but I'm still trying to understand why it was working locally.